# Undefined alert box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting undefined in the alert box by this following code where actually i have to get Hello in the alert box.
Please correct if any mistakes
    
    
    
    jQuery tutorial

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="Hello"> 



</body>
</html>


//alert.js code//
var print= $('#name').val();
alert(print);
```

Comment: Is your js file added in head or at the bottom of body tag? The issue might be that you are calling the js code even before the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: ^ Either that or you have not included jQuery library before using it.

Comment: DOM might not be loaded, to make sure your element is there in DOM Try this :$(function(){
        var print= $('#name').val();
        alert(print);
    });

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. See:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="name" value="Hello">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xb6r3phw/

Try to alert('hello') and check.

Comment: Make sure you include the jquery as I did above.

Comment: What do you mean not working in notepad? Did you include the path for jquery? Paste your entire code and I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below script.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($('#name').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" value="Hello">
```